# Solving equation and getting answer where two plots meet

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, equation-solving

I have two plots I created in matlab / octave I would like them to cross at x=4 or any other point on x I choose.  How can I go about doing this in matlab or octave?

Example code:

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
y = 1./exp(x); % 
%subplot(2,1,1); 
plot(x,y,'r')
title('e(x)')
hold on

y2 = -y+.09; % 
%subplot(2,1,2); 
plot(x,y2,'b')
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your second equation to be

```
y2 = -y+c
```

Then

```
1/exp(x) = -1/exp(x) + c
```

thus

```
c = 2/exp(x)
```

so just choose what the x-value of the intersection should be, plug it in that formula and that's your `c`. So for a crossing at `x==4`, `c=2/exp(x`) which is `0.036631` so

```
y2 = -y + 0.036631
```

So (assuming you can alter `c`) all you need to choose the x-vlaue of the point of intersection is to put that desired x-value into the equation

```
c = 2/exp(x)     %//note this is a scalar value of x, not the whole vector
```